# Oscillating values

Tags: processing, trigonometry

I'm doing some experiments in Processing, and I often need an int or float that oscillates between two values, like goes from 0 to 255 and then back to 0 incrementing 1 value at a time. I usually write some kind of boolean toggle method to do this, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this?

Like, is there a method where you can:

```
oscillate(0, 255, 1);
```

which does what I described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want specific control over how your oscillations are done and calculated then nothing beats writing your own functions for it. But if you're looking for something built in, then check out the `sin()` function which is an implementation of the mathematical function [sine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine). In fact, even in my own functions I use `sin` and `cos` functions provided by Processing. Just play with the values you multiply the output of the function with as it oscillates between -1 and 1.Multiplying it with a specific number will give you what you want. And then casting it to an `int` will get you integer values.

An example of this `sin()` function in action can be seen [here](http://www.learningprocessing.com/examples/chapter-13/example-13-6/). Code from the page is reproduced here for the sake of reference:

```
// Learning Processing
// Daniel Shiffman
// http://www.learningprocessing.com

// Example 13-6: Oscillation

float theta = 0.0;

void setup() {
  size(200,200);
  smooth();
}


void draw() {
  background(255);

  // The output of the sin() function oscillates smoothly between -1 and 1. 
  // By adding 1 we get values between 0 and 2. 
  // By multiplying by 100, we get values between 0 and 200 which can be used as the ellipse's x location.
  float x = (sin(theta) + 1) * width/2; 

  // We can also use Processing's "map()" function to achieve the same results
  // http://processing.org/reference/map_.html
  // float x = map(sin(theta),-1,1,0,width);

  // With each cycle, increment theta
  theta += 0.05;

  // Draw the ellipse at the value produced by sine
  fill(0);
  stroke(0);
  line(width/2,0,x,height/2);
  ellipse(x,height/2,16,16);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like waves... That's a triangle wave i think...

Try this one:

```java
int x;
void setup(){
  frameRate(6);
}

void draw(){

  println(sawWave (x, 4));
x++;
}

int sawWave(int value, int max){

 return (abs(abs( value% (max*2) - max) - max));
}
```

and here some more waves you can use. Click the sketch to go for next one...

```java
PGraphics [] pg = new PGraphics[4];
int w_dim = 1000;
PFont font;
ArrayList<PVector> points = new ArrayList<PVector>();
float[] f;
float x, res = 1;
String expression = "";
int expr = 0;
float valInput;

void setup() {
  // golden ratio :P
  size(w_dim, int(w_dim/1.6180));
  smooth();
  background(255);

  pg[0] = createGraphics(width, height, JAVA2D);

  font = loadFont("STHeitiSC-Medium-48.vlw");

  //draw graph lines
  pg[0].beginDraw();
  pg[0].stroke(240);
  pg[0].line(0, height/2, width, height/2);
  pg[0].line(0, height/2 - 112, width, height/2 - 112);
  pg[0].line(0, height/2 + 112, width, height/2 + 112);
  pg[0].endDraw();
}

void draw() {
  frame.setTitle(nf(frameRate, 2, 2));

  /*XXXXXX*/

  background(255);

  x +=res;
  float xR = radians(x); 


  switch (expr) {

  case 0:
    valInput = sin(xR);
    expression = "y = sin(x)";
    break;

  case 1:
    valInput = sin(tan(xR)*pow(sin(xR), 10));
    expression = "y = sin(tan(x)*sin(x)ˆ10";
    break;

  case 2:
    valInput = pow(sin(xR*PI), 12);
    expression = "y = (sin(x*PI))ˆ12";
    break;

  case 3:
    valInput   = cos(sin(xR*3)+xR*3);
    expression = "cos(sin(x*3)+x*3";
    break;

  case 4:
    valInput   = x%100/100;
    expression = "(x%100/100)";
    break;

  case 5:
    valInput   = sin(tan(cos(xR)*1.2));
    expression = "sin(tan(cos(x)*1.2";
    break;

  case 6:
    valInput   = cos(xR)*sin(xR);
    expression = "cos(x)*sin(x)";
    break;

  case 7:
    valInput   = sin(xR)*sin(xR*1.5);
    expression = "cos(x)*sin(x*1.5)";
    break;

  case 8:
    valInput   = sin(tan(xR)*0.05);
    expression = "sin(tan(x)*0.05";
    break;

  case 9:
    valInput   = cos(sin(xR*3))*sin(xR*0.2);
    expression = "cos(sin(x*3))*sin(x*2)";
    break;

  case 10:
    valInput   = sin(pow(8, sin(xR)));
    expression = "sin(8ˆsin(x))";
    break;

  case 11:
    valInput   = sin(exp(cos(xR*0.8))*2);
    expression = "sin(eˆcos(x*0.8)*2";
    break;

  case 12:
    valInput   = sin(xR-PI*tan(xR)*0.01);
    expression = "sin(x-PI*tan(x)*0.01";
    break;

  case 13:
    valInput   = pow(sin(xR*PI), 12);
    expression = "sin(x*PI)ˆ12";
    break;

  case 14:
    valInput   = cos(sin(xR)*tan(xR*PI)*PI/8);
    expression = "cos(sin(x)*tan(x*PI)*PI/8";
    break;

  case 15:
    valInput   = cos(sin(xR*3)+xR*3);
    expression = "cos(sin(x*3))+x*3";
    break;

  case 16:
    valInput   = pow(abs(sin(xR*2))*0.6, sin(xR*2))*0.5;
    expression = "|(sin(x*2)*0.6)ˆsin(x*2)*0.5|";
    break;

  case 17:
    valInput   = abs(xR % (2) - 1);
    expression = "|x%2-1|";
    break;

  case 18:
    valInput   = sin(xR)*tan(xR)*0.1;
    expression = "sin(x)*tan(x)*0.1";
    break;

  case 19:
    valInput   = sin(tan(xR)); 
    expression = "sin(tan(x))";
    break;

  case 20:
    valInput   = (cos(xR) * sin(xR*30) )* 0.3;
    expression = "(cos(x) * sin(x*30))*0.3";
    break;

  case 21:
    valInput   = cos(xR*(xR*0.5));
    expression = "cos(x*(x*0.5))";
    break;

  case 22:
    valInput   = cos(xR) * (tan(xR*0.5)*0.1);
    expression = "cos(x)* tan(x*0.5)*0.1";
    break;

  case 23:
    valInput   = sqrt(abs(sin(xR))); 
    expression = "squareRoot(|sin(x)|)";
    break;

  case 24:
    valInput   = sqrt(abs(sin(xR)*sin(xR*2))); 
    expression = "squareRoot(|sin(x)*sin(x*2)|)";
    break;

  case 25:
    valInput   = sqrt(abs(sin(xR)*sin(xR*10)));  
    expression = "squareRoot(|sin(x)*sin(x*10)|)";
    break;

  case 26:
    valInput   = tan(sin(xR)*cos(xR*3)); 
    expression = "tan(sin(x)*cox(x)";
    break;
  case 27:
    valInput   = sin(tan(cos(xR)));
    expression = "sin(tan(cos(x))";
    break;
  }

  //float value = 
  // float value = 
  //float value = 
  //float value = 
  //float value 
  //float value 


  //println (value);

  //drawExpression(0, 0, width, height, value, "");
  image(pg[0], 0, 0);
  drawExpression(0, 0, width, height, valInput, x, expression);
}




void mouseReleased() {

  //background(255);
  pg[0].beginDraw();
  pg[0].background(255);
  pg[0].stroke(240);
  pg[0].strokeWeight(1);
  pg[0].line(0, height/2, width, height/2);
  pg[0].line(0, height/2 - 112, width, height/2 - 112);
  pg[0].line(0, height/2 + 112, width, height/2 + 112);
  pg[0].endDraw();
  x=0;
  expr= (expr+1)%29;
  println (expr);
}




void drawExpression (float _x, float y, float w, float h, float value_y, float value_x, String _expression)
{
  float v_center = h/2;
  float h_center = w/2;


  float pos_x = _x + value_x;
  float pos_y = (v_center + (-value_y * h/5));
  // points.add(new PVector(pos_x, pos_y));

  for (PVector p:points) {
    //point(p.x, p.y);
  }

  //draw wave
  pg[0].beginDraw();
  pg[0].stroke(0);
  pg[0].strokeWeight(2);

  pg[0].point(pos_x, pos_y);
  pg[0].endDraw();


  //erase this area 
  float v_size  = v_center - v_center/2;
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect( _x, _x, w, v_size);



  float el_x = h_center + (-value_y * w/4);
  float el_y = v_size / 2;

  float c = map (value_y, -1, 1, 255, 0);
  float s = map (value_y, -1, 1, 2, 80);

  //draw pulse ellipse;
  fill(c);
  noStroke();
  fill(240);
  ellipse( w/2, el_y, s, s);


  //draw horizontal ellipse
  stroke(150, 200);
  strokeWeight(10);
  noFill();
  ellipse( el_x, el_y, 40, 40);

  // write value
  textFont(font, 20);
  fill(100);
  String st_y  = nfs(value_y, 3, 4);
  text("y = ", h_center - textWidth("y =")-200, 438);
  text(st_y, h_center - 200, 438);

  String st_x  = nfs( value_x, 3, 4);

  float line2_x1 =  h_center - textWidth("x = ") + 200 - textWidth(st_x) ;

  fill(100);
  text("x = ", line2_x1, 438);
  text(st_x, h_center + 200 - textWidth(st_x), 438);

  float line_x1 = line2_x1;

  float line_y = 438;
  float line2_y = 438;
  float line_x2 = h_center - textWidth("y =")-200;



  strokeWeight(0.5);
  stroke(220);

  line(line2_x1, line2_y, pos_x, pos_y);

  line(pos_x, 169, pos_x, 390);
  line(0, pos_y, width, pos_y);

  line(line_x2, line_y, pos_x, pos_y);

  stroke(200);
  line(line_x1, line_y, line_x1 + textWidth("x =" + st_x) + 4, line_y);
  line(h_center - textWidth("y =") - 200, line2_y, h_center - 200 + textWidth( st_y), line2_y);


  stroke(80);
  strokeWeight(6);
  point(pos_x, pos_y);

  //write expression
  textSize(25);
  fill(200);
  noStroke();
  text(_expression, width/2 - textWidth(_expression)/2, height - 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to oscillate variable is by using processing library [Ani](http://www.looksgood.de/libraries/Ani/) for animation. It simple define time and END value of animation for specific variable:

```
aniA = new Ani(this, 1.5, "x", 255);
```

If you want to to go back from 255 to 0 you just set mode to 'Ani.YOYO' and set 'repeat':

```
aniA.setPlayMode(Ani.YOYO);
aniA.repeat();
```

So whole oscillation would be like this:

```java
import de.looksgood.ani.*;

Ani aniA;
float y = 0;

void setup() {
  size(200,200);
  smooth();
  Ani.init(this);  
  aniA = new Ani(this, 1.5, "y", 200, Ani.QUAD_IN_OUT);
  aniA.setPlayMode(Ani.YOYO);
  aniA.repeat();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  stroke(0);

  line(width/2,0,y,height/2);
  ellipse(y,height/2,16,16);
}
```

You can also specific different easing for animation [here](http://www.looksgood.de/libraries/Ani/Ani_Cheat_Sheet.pdf)